# xPath can't find the indicated element

Tags: php, xpath

To illustrate my problem, I reduced it down to the following:

```
<?php
    $html = "
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Test Body</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ";

    $dom = new DOMDocument($html);
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $result = $xPath->query("//html/head/title");
    var_dump($result);

    $title = $result->item(0);
    var_dump($title);
?>
```

I'm trying to extract the title text. Running this, the returned node list is of length 0, so obviously the second check fails as well:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\partials\testPage.php:17:
object(DOMNodeList)[3]
  public 'length' => int 0

C:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\partials\testPage.php:20:null
```

This is such a simple example, I'm either grossly misunderstanding something, or I need some kind of pre-configuration (but I haven't seen that to be necessary in examples).

Comment: Why not just use `explode()` ?

Comment: make sure the dom parsed properly, e.g. try searching for `//html` only, and see if that node gets picked up, or do something like `echo $dom->saveHTML()` and see what comes out again.

Comment: @MarcB `//html` isn't parsed properly either.

Comment: @OliverQueen This is an overly simplified example.

Comment: then do the $dom->saveHTML() and see what pops out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TechNyquist points out, you do not build a DOMDocument that way.

Try with:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

I have tried with,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xPath->query("//html/head/title");
// var_dump($result);

$title = $result->item(0);
var_dump($title->textContent);
```

and got as expected

```
string(10) "Test Title"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that the Dom document constructor was a shortcut for `loadHTML`. I'll try this when I'm on break, thanks.

Comment: You were right. Feeding the html via `loadHTML` instead of the constructor fixed it.

Comment: for reference, no it does not: `public DOMDocument::__construct ([ string $version [, string $encoding ]] )`, [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php)